# How do I use ggplot2 stat_smooth to plot a glmer model with random effects?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use stat_smooth to plot the glmer model with general form: Y~X+(1+X|group), but I'm not sure how specify the arguments. I've gotten to this point:

```
ggplot(df1,aes(x=X,y=Y,group=s)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="glmer", method.args=list(formula=y~x+(1+x|group), family="binomial", control=glmerControl()), se=TRUE)
```

Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
grouping factors must have > 1 sampled level

My group is a factor with 3 levels, so I'm not sure what the problem is here. Another error I encounter is:

Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
start must be a list or a numeric vector

I have no idea what this even means. Can anyone tell me how to get around this?

Comment: This... might not work. I'd strongly suggest not trying to get too fancy fitting models inside `ggplot`--it's a graphics package not a modeling package. Fit your model first, generate a dataframe of predictions you want to plot, and then plot it.

Comment: The issue is that if you set a `group` aesthetic, ggplot treats each group separately---it will try to fit a model for each group. This works fine for models like `lm` or `loess`. But with a `glmer` model with random effects, you need a single model fit to all the data, but you still need ggplot to plot the predictions/lines separately (in different aesthetic groups). There may be ways around it within `stat_smooth`, but I don't know them.

Comment: might just need to define `s<-factor(s)`

Comment: Gregor, you're probably right, it just felt like it was so close to working!

Comment: Setting s <- factor(s) doesn't work in the formula, and doesn't fix the problem outside  of the model.